# Get value from script with popup

Tags: javascript, c#, gridview

I need a item detail from a gridview in a PopUp. When I click on detail on my gridview, I get the items from the row.

This is part of my grid:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvwProdProv" runat="server" CssClass="mGrid" 
   AutoGenerateColumns="false" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" 
   AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" Font-Size="Smaller" >
   <Columns>
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CLIENTE">
       <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID = "lblSAC_CliCod" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("cliente_Codigo") %>'></asp:Label>
       </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="COD. CAJA">
       <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID = "lblSAC_CajCod" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("caja_Codigo") %>'></asp:Label>
       </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="NUM">
        ...
        ...
     <asp:TemplateField>
       <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkView" Text="Detalle" NavigateUrl="javascript:;" runat="server" />
       </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I'm using this script for send values to the other webform:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $("[id*=lnkView]").click(function () {
      var rowIndex = $(this).closest("tr")[0].rowIndex;
      window.open("Detalle.aspx?rowIndex=" + rowIndex, "Popup", "width=700,height=200");
    });
  });
</script>
```

And the details are displayed in webform details, here I have the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    if (window.opener != null && !window.opener.closed) {
      var rowIndex = window.location.href.split("?")[1].split("=")[1];
      var parent = $(window.opener.document).contents();
      var row = parent.find("[id*=gvwProdProv]").find("tr").eq(rowIndex);
      $("#cliente_codigo").html(row.find("td").eq(0).html());
      $("#caja_codigo").html(row.find("td").eq(1).html());
      $("#caja_numero").html(row.find("td").eq(2).html());
    }
  });
</script>
```

I can get the values as selected:

```
<div>
  <u>Details</u>
  <br />
  <br />
  <b>Cliente:</b> <span id="cliente_codigo"></span>
  <br />
  <b>Codigo Caja:</b> <span id="caja_codigo"></span>
  <br />
  <b>Numero Caja:</b> <span id="caja_numero"></span>
</div>
```

The problem is I cannot get this values in variables for executing in store procedures, for display the details in gridview details.

How can I get them?

Comment: Can you be more specific, your Grid does?

Comment: Thanks Greg,  The first gridview show ítems. The second one must show the item details when you click on detail cell on the first.  With the scripts i can get values, but the values are in spans and I cant get them for the query for the second gridview. I hope to be more specific.

Comment: Do you do ` PostBack` to populate those spans?  So the user is in a Grid, they click a button, it displays more information about what they selected?

Comment: No, the script makes a Window.open and send values to the 2nd webform. This is the script: function () { $("[id*=lnkView]").click(function () { var rowIndex = $(this).closest("tr")[0].rowIndex; window.open("Detalle.aspx?rowIndex=" + rowIndex, "Popup", "width=700,height=200"); }); });............ i can get values, but i cant use them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment's, you appear to be thinking more like a traditional application.  However, a web-application will thrive under a stateless flow.  This was the major drawback to Web-Forms, it dictated a state to something that was intended to be stateless.

I'm not entirely sure your application goal... However, a secondary Form, I'm assuming could easily receive values in the following approach:

```
$('.Grid-Button').click(function () {
     // Logic to obtain value on Grid 
     window.open("Detail.aspx?index=1");
});
```

The JavaScript will be tweaked, but on the new page inside the `PageLoad` you would simply do the following:

```
var index = Request.QueryString["Index"];
```

That will provide a `string` value of `1`.  So at that point you could use the data however you wish, but it sounds like you would have a structure more like:

```
public void PageLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var index = Request.QueryString["Index"];
     if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty)
     {
          // Open database to build detail about Product.
     }
}
```

That I believe is what you're after.  Eventually you may want to look into either using a Single Page, Web-Service, or even convert your current approach to Ajax.  This way you don't have a popup, since some people have popup blockers, it is also considered annoying to most users.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thanks Greg.
I did that, but that's my problem, I cannot retrieve the values, because I send them in this manner:
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("[id*=lnkView]").click(function () {
                var rowIndex = $(this).closest("tr")[0].rowIndex;
                window.open("Detalle.aspx?rowIndex=" + rowIndex, "Popup", "width=700,height=200");
            });
        });
    </script>

Comment: Did you request the query string like I suggested?

Comment: Thanks Greg
The way I send them and I wanted retrieve them was not the best. anyway I send them with the hyperlink in my gridview like this:
<ItemTemplate>
          <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkView" Text="Detalle" runat="server" 
             NavigateUrl='<%# "Detalle.aspx?cliCod=" + Eval("cliente_Codigo").ToString() 
                         + "&cajCod=" + Eval("caja_Codigo").ToString() 
                         + "&cajNum=" + Eval("caja_Numero")
                         %>'/>
     </ItemTemplate>
And I retrieve them:
string clienteCodigo = Request.QueryString["cliCod"];
...
Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Greg,
You're right, it is not complicated send values, but the way I send them and I wanted retrieve them was not the best.
anyway I send them with the hyperlink in my gridview like this:

```
> <asp:TemplateField>
     <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkView" Text="Detalle" runat="server" 
             NavigateUrl='<%# "Detalle.aspx?cliCod=" + Eval("cliente_Codigo").ToString() 
                         + "&cajCod=" + Eval("caja_Codigo").ToString() 
                         + "&cajNum=" + Eval("caja_Numero")
                         %>'/>
     </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
```

And I retrieve them:

```
> string clienteCodigo = Request.QueryString["cliCod"];
string cajaCodigo = Request.QueryString["cajCod"];
string cajaNumero = Request.QueryString["cajNum"];
```